# Sorting the values within a dropdown widget in ipython notebook

Tags: python, widget, jupyter-notebook

I want to use the dropdown widget present within the IPython Notebook widgets. A simple example is shown below ...

```
from IPython.display import display
from IPython.html    import widgets
import random

genName = lambda : ''.join([chr(random.randint(65, 90)) for i in range(10) ])

testValues = [ genName() for i in range(20) ]
testValues = sorted(testValues)
testValues = dict(zip(testValues, testValues)) # This is not sorted because it is a dict
xx = widgets.DropdownWidget(values=testValues)

display(xx)
```

Now, the values to be inserted within the `DropdownWidget` accepts a dictionary, which as we well know in not a sorted element. The problem with this is that when we want to create a widget and arrange the valeus within the dropdown list in a certain order, then it cannot be done, as in the example above.

In the example I am working with, I have created a set of widgets which will allow the user to select a file using the dropdown widget. I want the files to appear sorted by date. However, because of the way in which the values are added (using a dictionary) I dont seem to be able to do this effectively.

Anyone got any idea how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least 2 options:

1. use an OrderedDict instead of an classical dictionary, like

   ```
   from collections import OrderedDict
   ...
   testValues = OrderedDict(zip(testValues, testValues)) # from your example
   ```
2. if you don't require that the selection and the obtained value differ, 
   you can use a list instead of the dict as shown [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/3.x/examples/Interactive%20Widgets/Widget%20List.ipynb). This way the value of the widget always equals the selected text. Your example would look like

   ```
   ...
   testValues = [ genName() for i in range(20) ]
   testValues = sorted(testValues)
   xx = widgets.DropdownWidget(values=testValues)
   ...
   ```

Based on your code I assume you are using IPython 2.x. Note that in IPython 3.x the widget is called `widgets.Dropdown` and the keyword `values` is now `options`.

Comment: Great! This is perfect.